# gghighlight prints label_key

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting a bar graph using ggplot2 and highlighting particular bars using gghighlight.

But using gghighlight prints some label_key also in the output.

I want to remove the label_key printed on top plot.

Please help.

```
ggplot(data=plot, aes(x=subdomain_name, y=mean)) + 
geom_bar(stat="identity", color="blue", fill="blue",width = nrow(plot)/10)+
geom_text(aes(label=format(round(mean,2))),hjust=0)+
coord_flip() + theme(axis.line = element_blank(),axis.line.x = element_blank(),
axis.line.y = element_blank(),plot.margin=unit(c(-0.6,1,1,1),"cm"),
panel.background=element_blank(),panel.border=element_blank(),
axis.title.x = element_blank(),axis.title.y = element_blank() )
+ylim(0,max+(0.05*max)) + gghighlight(grepl('Domain',subdomain_name),
unhighlighted_colour = alpha("red",1),
label_key = NULL))
```

[image: This is the output. Now i want to remove the label_key printed on top of plot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you need `use_direct_label = FALSE`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(gghighlight)

plot <- data.frame(
  subdomain_name = c(paste("Domain ", letters[1:3]), "foo"),
  mean = 1:4
)

max <- 4

ggplot(data = plot, aes(x = subdomain_name, y = mean)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", color = "blue", fill = "blue", width = nrow(plot) / 10) +
  geom_text(aes(label = format(round(mean, 2))), hjust = 0) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme(
    axis.line = element_blank(), axis.line.x = element_blank(),
    axis.line.y = element_blank(), plot.margin = unit(c(-0.6, 1, 1, 1), "cm"),
    panel.background = element_blank(), panel.border = element_blank(),
    axis.title.x = element_blank(), axis.title.y = element_blank()
  ) +
  ylim(0, max + (0.05 * max)) +
  gghighlight(grepl("Domain", subdomain_name),
    unhighlighted_colour = alpha("red", 1),
    use_direct_label = FALSE
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2018-12-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You should set label_key to F like this: You can also try using `?guides`

```
library(gghighlight)

ggplot(data=plot, aes(x=subdomain_name, y=mean)) + 
geom_bar(stat="identity", color="blue", fill="blue",width = nrow(plot)/10)+
geom_text(aes(label=format(round(mean,2))),hjust=0)+
coord_flip() + theme(axis.line = element_blank(),axis.line.x = element_blank(),
axis.line.y = element_blank(),plot.margin=unit(c(-0.6,1,1,1),"cm"),
panel.background=element_blank(),panel.border=element_blank(),
axis.title.x = element_blank(),axis.title.y = element_blank() )
+ylim(0,max+(0.05*max)) + gghighlight(grepl('Domain',subdomain_name),
unhighlighted_colour = alpha("red",1),
label_key = F))
```